# Android custom UI code fails to draw when SDK is changed

Tags: android, sdk, android-custom-view

I'm using the code from http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/ as the basis for some custom UI code. The original code's AndroidManifest.xml contains code as follows:

```
<application>
...
</application>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="3"
/>
```

I modified this to:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"
/>
<application>
...
</application>
```

and the hand fails to draw. The background canvas draws fine, as does the handScrew (although its color seems incorrect). What's the issue? I need to update the SDK since I'll be using some APIs only available in newer SDKs.

Also notice that I moved the `<uses-sdk>` stuff above `<application>` otherwise a warning occurs. If I leave the `<uses-sdk>` stuff below `<application>` then any SDK version 'seems' to work and the hand draws properly. 'Seems' in quotes since it's probably not working right.

If the `<uses-sdk>` stuff is put above `<application>`, minSdkVersion="13" is the highest that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another bug occurred when I tried to run my app on Lollipop where the drawTextOnPath() call wasn't working (whereas it worked fine on KitKat). I found the issue and workaround here: [Canvas.drawTextOnPath(...) not working on Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738608/canvas-drawtextonpath-not-working-on-lollipop). This solution also works for this drawPath() problem.