# Draw a text on a circle path in android

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, ondraw, drawtext

I need to draw a text on a circle path.
I have tried the `drawTextOnPath()` method. But for texts  like "fertile window" in the image attched, the text rotates and is not readable.

[image: This is the way I need]

[image: The text "Fertile window" isnt readable]

Code I have used :

```
customPath2.addArc(mCircleRectF, 30F, 64.28F);
    customPaint2.setAntiAlias(true);
    customPaint2.setDither(true);
    customPaint2.setStrokeWidth(mCircleStrokeWidth);
    customPaint2.setColor(Color.parseColor("#93BE66"));
    customPaint2.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    customPaint2.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    canvas.drawPath(customPath2, customPaint2);

    titlePaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    titlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    titlePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);  titlePaint.setLetterSpacing(0.07F);
    titlePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    titlePaint.setTextSize(35f);

    canvas.drawTextOnPath("FERTILE WINDOW", customPath2, 0, 8, titlePaint);
```

Comment: So starting from the top, you want the first 90 degress to be "downward" text, then the next 180 degress "upward", and then the rest "upward" again? Using XML only? Are you doing any code? Its a bit unclear what you want. The shown behavior is the expected one. Specially since you can "rotate" the View, and keep all text readable from the same point of view.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337221/how-to-write-curved-text) might help you

Comment: @Bonatti - I have used `onDraw()` and not XML. I have created and drawn the paths.

Comment: @RRR - Yes, I did refer to that link. It says `drawTextOnPath()` but doesnt say how to rotate though. As in that example, the text is to the top left of the circle, it is readable. But in my example I want it in the bottom of the ring.

Comment: Refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738608/canvas-drawtextonpath-not-working-on-lollipop). He has the arc as well, and his text is shown in the right way.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to comments for their help, to draw the text "outward", make the arc **counterclockwise**.
In your example, *startAngle* becomes `94.28` and *sweepAngle* becomes `-64.28`.

Kotlin:

```kotlin
val enclosingRect = RectF(0f, 0f, 200f, 200f)
val path = Path()
path.addArc(enclosingRect, 94.28f, -64.28f)
canvas.drawTextOnPath("FERTILE WINDOW", path, 0f, 0f, myPaint)
```

Java:

```java
RectF enclosingRect = new RectF(0f, 0f, 200f, 200f);
Path path = new Path();
path.addArc(enclosingRect, 94.28f, -64.28f);
canvas.drawTextOnPath("FERTILE WINDOW", path, 0f, 0f, myPaint);
```

That was for texts at the bottom of the circle (from `0` to `180` or from `-180` to `-360` degrees).

For angles between `180` and `360` or `0` and `-180` degrees you want to draw the arcs **clockwise**.