# canvas.drawTextOnPath no longer working

Tags: android, watchface

Could someone please help me as I can no longer get drawTextOnPath to work?

The watch face I wrote doesn't work properly after upgrades to watch software (and phone) so I'm writing 
it again from scratch using the current watch face template (targetSdk 27). 
At the moment I have this (in a method following the set up of the background bitmap during the onCreate of the Engine class):

```
            Paint mDayDialPaint2 = new Paint();
        mDayDialPaint2.setColor(Color.RED);
        mDayDialPaint2.setTextSize(10f);
        mDayDialPaint2.setAntiAlias(true);
        mDayDialPaint2.setStrokeWidth(65f);
        mDayDialPaint2.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mDayDialPaint2.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
//      canvas.drawTextOnPath(wkendText, textPathDay, 1f, 4f, mDayDialPaint2);
        canvas.drawTextOnPath("abcdefgh", textPathDay, 1f, 4f, mDayDialPaint2);
        //View.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        //canvas.drawPath(textPathDay, mDayDialPaint2);
```

When I uncomment canvas.drawPath as a test, it works. So the path exists and is in the right place.

I've tried a variety of text sizes and stroke widths, several variations of style, with and without the text align.

Following suggestions from SO and other places I've also tried:

- setLayerType - 'non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context' because I'm not extending a View
- disabling hardware acceleration (in manifest).

I did find a SO post 
[Canvas.drawTextOnPath(...) not working on Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738608/canvas-drawtextonpath-not-working-on-lollipop)
that says drawTextOnPath is broken as of Lollipop and you have to rescale and recalculate everything on the canvas but it's a lot of work and I've seen several posts since then that seem to find it works ok so I suspect it's not necessary.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by calling that code later. Originally it was in the Engine.onCreate, following the initialization of the background and the watch face; now it is called at the end of the onApplyWindowinsets and works correctly.